# Icon inside of button?

Tags: c#

How do i add an icon like in the screenshot below inside of a button? I cannot seem to find how to do it.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HGcK.jpg]

Comment: Thanks Dante for adding the image :)

Comment: WinForms, WPF, web???

Comment: @DanielMošmondor Or we could give 3 answers, 1 for each framework. It's nice to come from google and find the answer anyways.

Answer (score 37):

In WinForms use `Button.Image` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.image.aspx)) like this:

```
private void SetMyButtonIcon()
 {
    // Assign an image to the button.
    button1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\Graphics\\My.ico");
    // Align the image and text on the button.
    button1.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;    
    button1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
 }
```

and you can use `Button.TextImageRelation` Property to set the [position of text and image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s020taz2.aspx) relative to each other:

- `Overlay`: image and text share the same space on a control.
- `ImageBeforeText`: the image is displayed horizontally before the text of a control.
- `TextBeforeImage`: the text is displayed horizontally before the image of a control.
- `ImageAboveText`: the image is displayed vertically above the text of a control.
- `TextAboveImage`: the text is displayed vertically above the image of a control.

Comment: If you put both Text and Image Alignment to MiddleLeft and put some space characters in front of the Text properties, it is possible to make the button autosize and changes its text dynamically so it fits perfectly, and the image does not override the text button.

Answer (score 11):

If you put the button on the form, you can right click on it and click properties and then go to "Image" and put in the image you want, them go to the bottom and click "TextImageRelation" and click the drop down menu then click "ImageBeforeText", you can make it however you want but i personally like image before text the best.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it works, but how to resize the image to fit/strech?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
    <Button>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="/Image/ok.png" />
            <TextBlock Text="Start Tasks" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 3):

WPF (and Silverlight) is offering a control called `Image`. As the name implies it's a container which can hold an image inside. Use such a control to represent the icon you want and then place it inside your `Button` through its `Content` property

like here:

```
<Button x:Name="btn_ControlRun">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="right.png"/>
        <Label Content="Start Tasks" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: Minor point, you have the Label and Image positions reversed compared to the OP's requirements.