# Which control supports Label with Close Button for windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Is it possible to get a Text with Close button option for a windows Forms Application.Please let me know if we have any Dev Express control is available for the below functionality.
[image]

Comment: Something like this: [Icon inside of button?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11483655/95573)

Comment: If you are looking for that specific image, you can look at [PictureBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks DevMan..It  looks good as expected but we need two functionalities (On close image click and text click).Hope we cannot achieve this with Button.

Comment: We do can creat a button with image and text but we cannt handle button click and image click seperately.I have a requirement to have image click and text click seperately.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this on across multiple interface. I would recommend you to create yourself an UserControl. (Or component if you prefer) Put a label and a pictureBox in the user control. Then implement the two ClickEvent needed.

```
public partial class UCTextWithImage : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler TextClick;
    public event EventHandler ImgClick;

    public UCTextWithImage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ImgClick != null)
            ImgClick(sender, e);
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextClick != null)
            TextClick(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Once done, build you project, so the new userControl become available in form designer toolbox. Then drag and drop this UserControl into your interface. Finally bind and implement the two click event.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this for only a few area, then the ButtonEdit is the closest to what you need.

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsButtonEdittopic

In the properties, you have a button array. Remove the default one and add a new one of type glyph. Set the glyph you want. You can then use the ButtonClick event for the ImageClick and Click event for the LabelClick. However, in LabelClick, you need to check if underlying control isn't a button.

Finally, you need to change the appearance so the ButtonEdit so it become exactly like a label instead of Textbox.

To do so :
1- BackGroundColor must be transparent
2- BorderStyle set to None

Also, with devexpress, in order to have appearance set be taken into consideration,  you need to remove the LookNFeel that overwrite everything...

So, it is possible but if you really want to, but userControl solution is easier.